# How to check and convert image data types in OpenCV using Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using various methods in `OpenCV` to preprocess some images. I often get errors relating to the data type when passing objects been methods eg:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image and select ROI
image1 = cv2.imread('image.png')
roi_1 = cv2.selectROI(image1) # spacebar to confirm selection
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# preprocesssing
imCrop_1 = image1[int(roi_1[1]):int(roi_1[1]+roi_1[3]), int(roi_1[0]):int(roi_1[0]+roi_1[2])]
grey1 = cv2.cvtColor(imCrop_1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thresh, bw_1 = cv2.threshold(grey1, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
canny_edge1 = cv2.Canny(bw_1, 50, 100)

#test=roi_1 # Doesn't work with error: /home/bprodz/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:182: error: (-5) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4! in function fastNlMeansDenoisingColored
#test = imCrop_1 # works
#test = grey1 # doesn't work with error above
#test = bw_1 # doesn't work with error above
#test = canny_edge1 # doesn't work with error above

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(test,None,10,10,7,21)

# Check object types
type(imCrop_1) # returns numpy.ndarray - would like to see ~ CV_8UC3 etc.
type(grey1) # returns numpy.ndarray
```

Presently I just use trial and error, is a there a more methodical approach that I can use for checking and converting between different object types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using wrong method, for this purpose, you may also get a hint from the method name you are using, as per documentation of [`cv2. fastNlMeansDenoisingColored`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html#fastnlmeansdenoisingcolored):

> src – Input 8-bit 3-channel image.
>
> dst – Output image with the same size and type as src .

So, if want to use `cv2. fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` then you need to convert the src mat to a 3-channel matrix which can be done as:

```
cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

But if you have gray-scale image, then you may use [`cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html#fastnlmeansdenoising), which accepts the both single channel and three channel as source mats, and save the step for converting the image.

You can also use `img.shape` to check the number of channels for a given matrix. it would return (100, 100) for a gray-scale matrix, (100, 100, 3) for 3-channel matrix and (100, 100, 4) for 4-channel matrix. You can also get the type of matrix using `img.dtype`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, do you know if there's a way to check the object type from Python? When errors are thrown regarding the type I get asked for types such as `CV_8UC3`. Is there a way to inspect an object to see what type it is? Cheers.

Comment: I have edited my answer to incorporate the desired changes.

Comment: btw the purpose to the question was actually regarding checking and converting types of objects and not how to get `cv2.fastN1MeansDenoising` to work- as in my original question I showed which solution works and also the result of `type()`. I tried the solution you offered `img.dtype` but this doesn't not yield something like `CV_8UC3`. You can refer to the comments in my original question for what I would like to see and what I have tried. Thanks.

Comment: It won't because you are using a Python wrapper for OpenCV C++ API, `CV_8UC` etc exist in native C++ `cv::Mat` object but not in Python numpy arrays, So there is no direct way of matching the `cv::Mat`  with numpy mat type.